# pattern matching gives return type as Any

Tags: scala

I am trying to do pattern matching on constants .
 I get return type of `c3` as `Any` but I want it to return `Option`

In case I don't use `isDefined` it can throw an error on `None`

```
 object Currency {

    sealed trait Currency {def name: String}

    case object EUR extends Currency {val name = "EUR"}

    //etc.
    case object INR extends Currency {val name = "INR"}

    //etc.

    val list = Seq(EUR, INR)

    def currency(name: String): Option[Currency] = list.find(_.name == name)
  }

  val c1=Currency.currency("INR")
  val c3=if(c1.isDefined)c1.get match {
    case Currency.INR => Currency.EUR
    case Currency.EUR=> Currency.INR
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the else case in your if statement., if you want to return an Option

```
val c3=if(c1.isDefined){
      c1.get match {
        case Currency.INR => Some(Currency.EUR)
        case Currency.EUR=> Some(Currency.INR)
    }
  else None
```

However, this is a poor use of Option.  Checking for existence, extracting the value then packing it back up is something you should never do.  In this case, what you want is `map`

```
val c3 = c1.map{
    case Currency.INR => Currency.EUR
    case Currency.EUR => Currency.INR 
    }
```

Will return an `Option[Currency]` containing the updated value according to your mapping, and `None` if the option was none.

Note that if the contents is a currency not included as a match case then a match exception will be thrown.  In this case it's not a concern because you are using a sealed trait making this an exhaustive match.

If needed though, you can include a default case to cover that scenario,

```
val c3 = c1.map{
    case Currency.INR => Currency.EUR
    case Currency.EUR => Currency.INR
    case _ => Currency.INR //catch-all.  Anything not covered in previous
                             cases will default to Currency.INR
    }
```

The above returns `Some(Currency.EUR)` is c1 is `Some(Currency.INR)`, `Some(Currency.INR)` is C1 contains any other `Some`, and `None` is C1 is `None`

or use `collect` instead of `map` to make it return `None` if no cases match.

```
val c3 = c1.collect{
    case Currency.INR => Currency.EUR
    case Currency.EUR => Currency.INR
    }
```

The above returns `None` if c1 is anything other than `Some(Currency.INR)` or `Some(Currency.EUR)`

Comment: can you please explain the last point  In general though, you can include a default case to cover that scenario, or use collect instead of map to make it return None if no cases match.

Comment: @coder25 I updated the answer, let me know if you still need clarification on any points

Comment: ok collect is used to create a collection right how it helps in pattern matching

Comment: @coder25 `collect` is like `filter` and `map` combined